# Efeito em ancora

Tags: javascript, jquery

como colocar um efeito de lentidão na minha ancora?

```html
<button href="#grafico_relatorio" type="button" id="gerar_grafico"class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d">Gerar Gráfico</button>
```

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres dizer por _"efeito de lentidão"_?

Comment: ao invés de clicar e a tela se movimentar rapidamente para a div da ancora, ele ir lentamente.